# PHP Google Gdata API

Tags: php, gdata, google-docs-api, zend-gdata

I am trying to integrate Google Docs with my web application which is written by PHP. I know that Zend Gdata client library can work and actually I did implement some of the features by using it. But the problem I have is that Zend Gdata client library doesn't support OAuth 2.0 which is recommended by Google.
   I don't know if I can write a script to get access by OAuth 2.0 and use the returned access token in the current version of Zend Gdata. Or if there are any other PHP Google document list API client libraries.
Thanks for your help.


**UPDATE**
According to my test. You can use OAuth 2.0 with Zend Gdata. The basic idea is:

1. Use CURL to get the access token.
2. Save the access token and use it like you use the code from AuthSub.

Hopefully it can help someone out there who has to same questions as me.

Comment: (You can add your update as an answer and accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test. You can use OAuth 2.0 with Zend Gdata. The basic idea is:

Use CURL to get the access token.
Save the access token and use it like you use the code from AuthSub.
Hopefully it can help someone out there who has to same questions as me.

Comment: but I got "Expected response code 200, got 403 Token invalid - Invalid token: Cannot parse referred token string"